# Calling system with std::string?

Tags: c++

I'm passing two std::string's to a function that is creating an alias and echoing it to bashrc in linux and having some problems.

Anyhow, since system() is expecting a char this won't work and I can't seem to figure it out, thanks in advance! (Here is a code snippet that hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to say)

```
#include <iostream>

int create_alias(std::string&, std::string&);

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}

int create_alias(std::string &alias, std::string &name)
{
    #ifndef __linux__
        std::cout << "Program not  supported, aborting!";
        return 1;
    #endif
    if ( system("echo alias " + name + "='" + alias + "' >> .bashrc") != 0 )
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system` function expects a `const char*` parameter. Form a string and then supply the [pointer to a null terminated character array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to the `system` function:

```
std::string s = "echo alias " + name + "='" + alias + "' >> .bashrc";
if (system(s.c_str()) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `yourstring.c_str()`, it returns a `char *`.

Also, using `system()` is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong), you could just write to `.bashrc` via `fstream`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code just uses echo to write a basic command to .bashrc, that code would be fine in a shell script, not in a C++ app. Just use basic file I/O to implement the `create_alias()` function

Comment: @nos: there may be other things the program does or will do that warrant using C++.  Anyway, using `ofstream` in append mode is definitely safer (and will be much faster to execute, not that it's likely to matter) than `system()`, so good answer.

Answer (score 0):

to get a const char * from a string you use .c_str()

```
string msg="echo alias " + name + string("='" + alias + "' >> .bashrc";
system(msg.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `std::string::c_str()` method to get a `const char *` from a `std::string`, eg:

```
int create_alias(const std::string &alias, const std::string &name)
{
    #ifndef __linux__
    std::cout << "Program not supported, aborting!";
    return 1;
    #else
    std::string cmd = "echo alias " + name + "='" + alias + "' >> .bashrc";
    if ( std::system(cmd.c_str()) != 0 )
        return 1;
    return 0;
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `std::string::c_str()` function returns a `const char*` C string:

```
if ( system( (std::string("echo alias ") + 
              name + 
              "='" + 
              alias + 
              "' >> .bashrc").c_str() ) != 0 )
```